# Trying to enter a directory from the first line of another file

Tags: command-line, csh

Currently using csh at workplace.

So what i currently have is a path stored in the first line of a file and i am trying to read that.

```
head -n 1 jvar.txt
```

Now i have to go to that path so i was trying to store this in a variable

```
set a = head -n 1 jvar.txt
```

but its not able to store it in sayin Illegal variable name. The idea was to then do cd $a and go to that path. is there any way i can store it to something so i can cd to that path.

Comment: Variable affectation & output of a command: `a=$(head -n 1 jvar.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

To capture the output of the head command into a string that you can assign to a variable, you need [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

In `csh`, that is done by enclosing the command in backticks:

```
set a = `head -1 jvar.txt`        # csh
```

The backtick syntax also works in `bash`, but is deprecated in favour of `$(...)`. Also note that in bash and similar Bourne/Korn derived shells, it is an error to include whitespace around the `=` operator:

```
a=$(head -1 jvar.txt)             # bash, ksh, sh etc.
```

Comment: although  
set a = `head -1 jvar.txt`        # csh
worked for me but now whenever i try to do cd $a i get 
cd: Too many arguments
the intention was a is where the path would be copied from jvar.txt and i could go to that path from there

Comment: @JovinMiranda if the path has spaces (or other shell-special characters) you will need to quote it: `cd "$a"`